# How to register a custom HttpMessageConvertor in spring-boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using spring-boot REST service and it need to transform incoming json field to custom entities. But I am not able to get the custom converter working.

I am sure I am missing something very obvious here but can't figure out what!

I have the following JSON which I want to convert into Item Entity

```
{
    'item_name':'some item name',
    'item_category':'some item catagory',
    'status_date_flag':'T',
    'item_sale_date':'2015-10-28' 
}
```

Item Entity

```
class Item{

    private String itemName;
    private String catagory;
    private boolean isDateFlagOn;
    private LocalDate saleDate;

    //...
    //public getters/setters
}
```

I have created a custom message converter

```
@Component
public class ItemMessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Item> {

    public ProductMessageConverter() {
        super(MediaType.ALL);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz.getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase(Item.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    protected Product readInternal(Class<? extends Item> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
         System.out.println("readInternal GETTING called......................");

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Product product, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        System.out.println("writeInternal GETTING called......................");
    }
}
```

I have created a configuration class for registering the HttpMessageConverter

```
@Configuration
public class MyBootConfiguration {
    @Bean public HttpMessageConverters customConverters(){
        HttpMessageConverter itemMessageConverter = new ItemMessageConverter();
        return new HttpMessageConverters(itemMessageConverter);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you need a custom converter for that? Also why are you wrapping it again in that `@Bean` method? Create a configuration class which extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and implement/override the `extendMessageConverters` for that. But looking at it nothing in what you have cannot be done with plain Jackson already. So still why would you need that custom converter??

Comment: I need it as there are fields in json like `String status_date_flag` and `String date` in a different format than what is expected from the Item format. I tried this in configuration class but its not working `@Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new ItemMessageConverter());
    }`

Comment: So and why should that matter. Add a couple of `@JsonProperty` annotations to the class instead of writing a custom mapper for each and every object.

Comment: I have updated the question to add conversion to LocalDate as part of the json. I believe now it makes sense to use `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` ?

Comment: No it still doesn't as jackson is perfect capable of converting that, if joda time is detected spring will even add default support for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is achievable by a custom Jackson converter. Change your `Item` class definition like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

@JsonDeserialize(using = ItemDeserializer.class)
public class Item {
    private String itemName;
    private String category;
    private boolean isDateFlagOn;
//constructor, getters and setters
}
```

The annotation indicates this class should be deserialized via `ItemDeserializer`, here is the implementation of it:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

public class ItemDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer {
    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        String itemName = node.get("itemName").textValue();
        String category = node.get("category").textValue();
        String flagStr = node.get("isDateFlagOn").textValue();

        return new Item(itemName, category, Objects.equals(flagStr, "T"));
    }
}
```

This code works fine in Spring 4.2 with following handler:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @RequestMapping("jsonGreeting")
    public ResponseEntity jsonGreeting(@RequestBody Item item, BindingResult result) throws Exception {
        if (result.hasErrors()){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("parse error: " + result.getAllErrors().toString());
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(item.toString());
    }
}
```