# Intercept request to create RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc

I have a base CreateRequest class which I inherit in a couple of children, each responsible for some custom validations:

Base:

```
public class CreateEventRequest {

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty
    private Boolean isPrivate;
}
```

Child:

```
public class CreateRegularEventRequest extends CreateEventRequest {

    @NotNull
    @Future
    private LocalDateTime startTime;

    @NotNull
    @Future
    private LocalDateTime endTime;

    public LocalDateTime getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }
}
```

In order to take advantage of the validations, I've tried this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<CreateEventResponse> createEvent(HttpEntity<String> httpEntity,
                                                           @AuthenticationPrincipal SecuredUser user) {
        try {
            CreateEventRequest eventRequest = eventRequestFactory.getEventRequestString(httpEntity.getBody());

            Set<ConstraintViolation<CreateEventRequest>> violations = validator.validate(eventRequest);

            if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
                throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
            }

            return new ResponseEntity<>(this.service.createEvent(eventRequest, user), HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }
    }
```

My factory is:

```
 public CreateEventRequest getEventRequestString(String json) {
        try {
            String eventTypeRaw = new ObjectMapper().readTree(json)
                    .get("event_type").asText();

            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(eventTypeRaw)) {
                EventType eventType = EventType.valueOf(eventTypeRaw);

                if (EventType.REGULAR.equals(eventType)) {
                    return objectMapper.readValue(json, CreateRegularEventRequest.class);
                } else if (EventType.RECURRING.equals(eventType)) {
                    return objectMapper.readValue(json, CreateRecurringEventRequest.class);
                }
            }

            return null;
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This seems really hacky to me and do not scale for future Parent-Child relation, my question is, is there a way to intercept this request to create this child classes and pass it to the controller or some built-in validations to handle this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you think decorator pattern or Lombok's @Delegate annotation could help you here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with neither, would you mind elaborating a bit? P.S. Thus far I'm trying to avoid using Lombok, but if it solves the problem I'd gladly do so! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Did yo try:

```java
public ResponseEntity<CreateEventResponse> createEvent( @Valid @RequestBody  CreateRegularEventRequest reqBody ...) {
..
```

all the mapping and validation are done automatically

Comment: The problem is that I have 2 children, doing so would require me to create 2 distinct routes, which I'm trying to avoid here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: from the code , i can see that after validation you always pass to the service a CreateEventRequest, in case you need to pass different objects , you will have implement the same logic for the others children. so to avoid that  u can try to request a nested object in the controller (like, global class having the children as properties) or implementing a [Message Converter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-message-converters)

Comment: Is it possible to use a MessageConverter in a single route? Thanks

Comment: i dont think so, the best way is a nested object and maybe a custom Jackson converter, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503046/how-to-register-a-custom-httpmessageconvertor-in-spring-boot)